# JQuery issue with addClass method

Tags: jquery, addclass

Thank you in advance for any assistance.  I'm having difficulty completing a very simple case of the addClass method.  I've read a bunch of resources and still can't figure it out.  Any idea why this wouldn't work?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>.blueright {color:blue;}</style>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h4 id="test">asdf</h4>
        <script> $("#test").addClass("blueright"); </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you again! -Dan

Comment: Working http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/72mN7/

Comment: just fine http://plnkr.co/edit/xKvXBv3pIc38KzKGwmCq?p=preview

Comment: How are you opening the file?

Comment: are you loading the file using a `file://` url - loading the file from local file system instead of from a web server

Comment: This code is fine on the web, if you're testing on local machine you're not giving it the right address. Add an http:// in there, or just wait until you have it on the web and it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/72mN7/)

your code is working good.

---

Problem is with jQuery library loading

Try script URL

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

change with

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

---

Browser takes `//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js` it as

if your working on local pc than it will take is as `file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"`

but on server it takes it as `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"`

So better use `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`